# How to create dynamic color for highchart with dynamic dates?

Tags: highcharts

I have no idea how this is done ...because all this while i can only make highcharts with fixed color...for example A color #FFFFFF B color #000000.

Now i have a data that has dynamic date which is the last 30 days and this 30 days changes as the new date arrives. for example last 30 days from today is different last 30 days from tomorrow.

So what i want is to have different color for each of the day dynamically...like day 1 = red, day 2 = yellow, etc.....how it is done in highcharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the colors dynamically after receiving the data:

```
var data = [...],
  colors = [...];

return data.map((el, i) => ({
  y: el,
  color: colors[i]
}));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4925/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.color